# R string replacing part of javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm sure this is a noob question but I couldn't figure out how you would insert a R string object inside a javascript. For example,

`trackname <- "audiotrack1"`

into

`tag$script(var url = 'audioResources/' + trackname + '.wav')`

Where I would want to replace the "trackname" with "audiotrack1". I'm sure paste0 isn't the best way to do this. What is the standard way to go about doing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. You can do:

```
tags$script(HTML(sprintf("var url = 'audioResources/%s.wav'", trackname)))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `glue`

```
library(glue)
tags$script(HTML(glue::glue("var url = 'audioResources/{trackname}.wav'")))
```